# Show css when user scrolls down instead of up?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I found this tutorial http://benweiser.com/add-a-sticky-top-bar-widget-to-genesis-that-hides-and-reveals-on-scroll/ and liked the idea.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Hide Top bar on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var topbarHeight = $('.top-bar').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();


    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;


    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > topbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.top-bar').removeClass('bar-down').addClass('bar-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.top-bar').removeClass('bar-up').addClass('bar-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}

});
```

I was wondering if there's a way of doing the opposite of hiding the bar when the user is scrolling up, but displaying it while they are scrolling down.

I'm interested in putting some share buttons on it and displaying the buttons when the user is scrolling upwards wouldn't be very effective.

Answer (score 1):

i do not understand the question because in the if-else block ther stands:

```
// Scroll Down
```

and

```
// Scroll Up
```

so put your code to the IF when you want to add something when user scrolls down and to the ELSE if user scrolls up.

in this case: switch the code of IF and ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

Not CSS but a Jquery Example

On scroll down - the top bar is visible and on scroll up its hidden

```js
 $(document).ready(function($) {
   // Hide Top bar on on scroll down
   var didScroll;
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   var delta = 5;
   var topbarHeight = $('.top-bar').outerHeight();

   $(window).scroll(function(event) {
     didScroll = true;
   });

   setInterval(function() {
     if (didScroll) {
       hasScrolled();
       didScroll = false;
     }
   }, 250);

   function hasScrolled() {
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();


     if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
       return;



     if (st > lastScrollTop && st > topbarHeight) {
       // Scroll Down
       console.log('down');
       $('.top-bar').animate({
         'top': '0px'
       });
     } else {
       // Scroll Up

       if (st < $(document).height()) {
         console.log('up');
         $('.top-bar').animate({
           'top': '-65px'
         });
       }
     }

     lastScrollTop = st;
   }

 });
```

```css
.top-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  // Should be the same as padding top
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: -65px;
  // Add a nice transition
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  // Center the content if you so desire
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  // If your sticky bar gets hidden underneath some content set the z-index higher 
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='bar-up top-bar'>This is the top bar</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```